# how to change the container?

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

how to change the container depending on the number of elements in the list?

I want my text button at the bottom to move based on the number of items in the list.

these two widgets are in a column

the size of the leaf container is set to avoid an error

[image]

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        child: ReorderableListView(
          children: _workoutList
              .map(
                (item) => Slidable(
                  // Указываем клавишу, если Slidable можно закрыть.
                  key: ValueKey(item.id),

                  // Конечная панель действий находится справа строки
                  endActionPane: ActionPane(
                    //размер кнопки от листа
                    extentRatio: 1 / 6,
                    // Движение — это виджет, используемый для управления анимацией панели.
                    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                    // Панель может закрывать Slidable.
                    dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {
                      _workoutList.remove(item);
                    }),

                    children: [
                      CustomSlidableAction(
                          onPressed: (_) {},
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDE1509),
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(CupertinoIcons.delete),
                              Text(
                                S.of(context).textDel_CreatingWorkout,
                                style: ThemeText.textDel,
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      // SlidableAction(
                      // onPressed: (_) {},
                      // backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDE1509),
                      // foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      // icon: CupertinoIcons.delete,
                      // label: "Удалить",
                      // )
                    ],
                  ),

                  // Дочерний объект Slidable — это то, что видит пользователь, когда
                  // компонент не перетаскивается.
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.workout),
                    trailing: Transform.scale(
                      scaleX: 1.2,
                      child: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          //перемещение строк
          onReorder: (int start, int current) {
            // перетаскивание сверху вниз
            if (start < current) {
              int end = current - 1;
              String startItem = _workoutList[start].workout;
              int i = 0;
              int local = start;
              do {
                _workoutList[local].workout = _workoutList[++local].workout;
                i++;
              } while (i < end - start);
              _workoutList[end].workout = startItem;
            }
            // перетаскивание снизу вверх
            else if (start > current) {
              String startItem = _workoutList[start].workout;
              for (int i = start; i > current; i--) {
                _workoutList[i].workout = _workoutList[i - 1].workout;
              }
              _workoutList[current].workout = startItem;
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 0),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            creatingAnExercise(context);
          },
          child: Text(
            S.of(context).createButtonText_COED,
            style: ThemeText.createButtonText,
          ),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
              const Color(0xffFBFBFD),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

added a complete code snippet to understand the whole situation.
I will be glad for any help.The picture shows how everything is built.

[image]

Comment: Show your code for the clarity

Comment: can you share some code so we can help?

Comment: Whats your code?
I think you need to add `shrinkWrap: true` tthe ListView

Comment: but it seems by the output that you are wrapping both list and text with Expanded Widget because The List and the text are getting each on 50% of the layout, if that's the case you solve the problem by removing `Expanded` from your `Text`

Comment: added code for my error

Comment: `shrinkWrap: true`  and  `constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight:height)`
 solved my problem